# Выход из GUI. Ошибки в функционировании кнопок дочернего проекта

Tags: gui, matlab

Задача, как мне казалось тривиальная настолько, что споткнуться здесь невозможно в принципе.
Итак, есть окно GUI, созданное через guide. В окне имеются несколько полей для заполнения и кнопка "Ввод". Классика.
В Callbaсk-функции кнопки задано считывание полей и экспорт этих данных в INI.txt, после чего я вызываю основной проект, для которого эти данные являются входными, а окно GUI закрываю. В самом проекте также формируется несколько кнопок пользователя на окне фигуры (fugure), однако они перестают функционировать. Все, кроме "закрыть" с функцией close(gcbf). При этом, если закрыть проект вываливается множество ошибок 
[image: Больше ошибок богу ошибок]

Я так понимаю, что я каким-то образом продолжаю работать в GUI, несмотря на то, что я вызываю другой m-файл.
Были испробованы следующие варианты:
В функции кнопки (в GUI):close gcbf;close;delete(handles.*имя gui-проекта*);
В открываемом файле:

```
fig=findobj(0,'type','figure');
delete(fig);
```

а также close all
Подскажите, как быть?

*error смешной, а ситуация страшная*

Comment: Всё это настолько расплывчато. что ответить на вопрос невозможно

Comment: Хорошо, выражусь менее витиевато: Я захожу в GUI, делаю там все что мне нужно и нажимаю кнопку, в Callback-функции которой прописано следующее: close %закрытие окна GUI; PROJ%Наименование m-файла проекта. В результате окно GUI действительно закрывается, проект действительно открывается, однако кнопки в проекте не работают. Ни одна. Кроме той, у которой функция close(gcbf). А после закрытия проекта вываливаются ошибки (см. фото).

Comment: Похоже, что callback-функции нового окна пытаются что-то делать с объектами из закрытого окна, которые уже уничтожены. Поэтому работает только `close` - она ни к каким объектам не обращается

Comment: Как мне подсказали на экспоненте, GUIDE умер, да здравствует App Designer. Придется ставить что-то не ниже 2016 года, ибо он появился именно там. С Наступающим!)